# Combined SQL query misses operand (error #1241)... what am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm trying to combine 2 queries that do work when you use them as separate queries but it fails when they are being combination...

```
SELECT mm.id, mm.thread_id, mm.sender_id, u.user_nicename, mm.subject, mm.message       
FROM `x_bp_messages_messages` AS mm 
INNER JOIN `x_users` AS u
ON u.ID = mm.sender_id
```

Works.

```
SELECT mr.user_id, group_concat( mr.thread_id separator ',' ) 
FROM `x_bp_messages_recipients` AS mr 
WHERE mr.user_id = 61
```

Works.

But when I try to include the second query in a WHERE IN statement is fails with the error message : #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
SELECT mm.id, mm.thread_id, mm.sender_id, u.user_nicename, mm.subject, mm.message       
FROM `x_bp_messages_messages` AS mm 
INNER JOIN `x_users` AS u       
ON u.ID = mm.sender_id      
WHERE mm.thread_id IN (     
  SELECT mr.user_id, group_concat( mr.thread_id separator ',' ) 
    FROM `x_bp_messages_recipients` AS mr 
  WHERE mr.user_id = 61
)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm trying to build a function to allow our users to export their PM conversations they have had with others within the BuddyPress PM system as we are migrating to a forum based solution now, with it's own PM system.

=======
UPDATE: solved with the input from @gordon-linoff. The correct query is:

```
SELECT          
    mm.id, mm.thread_id, mm.sender_id, u.user_nicename, mm.subject, mm.message      
FROM            
    `x_bp_messages_messages` AS mm      
INNER JOIN          
    `x_users` AS u      
ON          
    u.ID = mm.sender_id     
WHERE           
    mm.thread_id IN (       
      SELECT mr.thread_id
      FROM `x_bp_messages_recipients` AS mr 
      WHERE mr.user_id = 61
    )
```

Thanks all for your lighting fast support!

Comment: Your `in` subquery is returning two columns.  That is clearly one problem.

Comment: Remove `mr.user_id` from subquery select.

Comment: Ah yes - that actually makes sense :|

Answer (score 1):

I think you intend:

```
WHERE mm.thread_id IN (SELECT mr.thread_id
                       FROM `x_bp_messages_recipients` mr 
                       WHERE mr.user_id = 61
                      )
```

You are confusing a string with commas with a list of values for `IN`.  There may be other errors in your query as well.

Comment: Thanks @gordon-linoff that does the trick when also removing the word separator :)